# Assigning SelectedValue of ComboBox to a string property of viewmodel wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, prism

So I have very simple `combobox` containing list of values. I am supposed to bind the `selectedvalue` to a `viewmodel` property and store it in DB. Below is my current approach:

**SampleViewModel.cs**

```
public class SampleViewModel: BindableBase
{
    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        MyDetails = new ObservableCollection<DetailItems>(){
            new DetailItems{Name="Detail1"},
            new DetailItems{Name = "Detail2"},
            new DetailItems{Name= "Detail3"},
            new DetailItems{Name="Detail4"}
        };
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DetailItems> _myDetails;
    private string _myDetail;

    public ObservableCollection<DetailItems> MyDetails { get { return _myDetails; } set { SetProperty(ref _myDetails, value); } }
    public string MyDetail { get { return _myDetail; } set { SetProperty(ref _myDetail, value); } }
}

public class DetailItems: BindableBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); } }
}
```

and my `ComboBox` in `View` is as follows

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbDetails" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyDetails}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                  SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding MyDetail}"/>
```

But whenever I get data in backend, the string `MyDetail` will have an instance of DetailItems converted to `string`. Could anyone let me know how I can change this to bind appropriate value to `MyDetail`?

Comment: You should not use binding inside SelectedValuePath. Use just Name there if you want value to be Name (like you already do in DisplayMemberPath).

Comment: @Evk.. Perfect buddy.. Thanks much for the quick response.. Could you please add it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is quite simple: `SelectedValuePath` expects path to the property of object, not binding (just like `DisplayMemberPath` does). So a fix would be:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbDetails" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyDetails}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValuePath="Name" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding MyDetail}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, **SelectedValue** always holds the currently selected item only. So you have to change the type from string to **DetailItems** as follow,

```
private DetailItems_myDetail;
 public DetailItems MyDetail { get { return _myDetail; } set { SetProperty(ref _myDetail, value); } }
}
```

if you want the selected name call **MyDetail.Name** it will return your string